# UUID с Postgresql + hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Не могу настроить `Id` для типа `UUID`. Все время выскакиевает ошибка `No identifier specified for entity: org.faoxis.startback.domain.Account`.

**Таблица:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS account (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,

  login VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

  email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

  firstname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  lastname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

  created_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

**`Entity`:**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id", columnDefinition = "UUID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private UUID id;

    private String login;
    private String password;

    private String email;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastName;
}
```

Перепробовал уже, наверное, все примеры из интернета - никак. Не понимаю, что я делаю не так.

Comment: Может это из-за того, что hiberbnate не поддерживает uuid postgres-а? Например eclipse не поддерживает, но можно составить конвертер и всё заработает. Для hibernat-а тоже можно создавать конвертеры.

Comment: @Sergey а как сделать конвертер для Id ? Вроде так нельзя: https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/

Comment: Пробовали указать формат @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")?

Comment: Например: https://thoughts-on-java.org/generate-uuids-primary-keys-hibernate/
Думаю - у вас не подключена конкретная стратегия, а ваша версия hibernate - не умеет использовать стратегию из дефолтного списка "uuid2".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начиная с Hibernate 5 можно просто

```
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;
}
```

И Hibernate сам решит какой тип определить для поля в таблице.