# Как задать SEQUENCE для столбца

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

Делаю запрос и можно заметить, что подставил `SEQUENCE`, раньше был `identity` и сейчас появилась ошибка, не дающая создать таблицу: `IDENTITY expected, got SEQUENCE`. Читал [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062328/sequence-vs-identity) ответ, но мне ничего не дал.

```
create table users
(
    id         bigint generated by default as SEQUENCE
        constraint users_pkey
            primary key,
    email      varchar(255) not null
        constraint uk_6dotkott2kjsp8vw4d0m25fb7
            unique,
    first_name varchar(255) not null,
    last_name  varchar(255) not null,
    password   varchar(255) not null,
    role       varchar(255),
    status     varchar(255)
);

alter table users
    owner to root;
```

Comment: `id serial primary key` без всего остального.

Comment: @nörbörnën можете написать этот ответ, я зачту его

Comment: хорошо, через часок

Comment: @nörbörnën как будет свободное время, посмотрите эти топики ещё, пожалуйста: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186470/id-in-table-public-city-found-serial-typesinteger-but-expecting-int8-types https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186469/schema-validation-missing-sequence-hibernate-sequence Комментарии под этим топиком после вашего ответа удалю. Спасибо.

Comment: я не умею в hibernate. но по опыту я бы сказал, что при проектировании энтитис, в случае недостатка опыта, надо плясать от ORM и использовать егойные best practices

Comment: кстати, о best practices, я бы вообще не морочился с `serial primary key`, а а использовал uuid-ы. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/681335/uuid-%D1%81-postgresql-hibernate

Comment: @nörbörnën я с liquibase работаю, как мне там этот запрос построить тогда?) в виде sql

Comment: я не знаю, я из другой экосистемы :) спроси у людей из топа метки hibernate, например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/hibernate/topusers

Comment: Ладно, хорошо, пока identity оставлю)