# id in table public.city; found serial (Types#INTEGER), but expecting int8 (Types#BIGINT)

Tags: java, liquibase

Почему вот эта строка `id serial primary key,` породило за собой вот эту ошибку `[id] in table [public.city]; found [serial (Types#INTEGER)], but expecting [int8 (Types#BIGINT)` Мне пришлось везде тип id с Long (bigint) менять на Integer.

Пример того, как использую создание таблиц в Liquibase:

```
create table users
(
    id serial primary key,
    email      varchar(255) not null
        constraint uk_6dotkott2kjsp8vw4d0m25fb7
            unique,
    first_name varchar(255) not null,
    last_name  varchar(255) not null,
    password   varchar(255) not null,
    role       varchar(255),
    status     varchar(255)
);

alter table users
    owner to root;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

следующее заявление:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
    id SERIAL
);
```

эквивалентно следующим утверждениям:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE table_name_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE table_name (
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('table_name_id_seq')
);

ALTER SEQUENCE table_name_id_seq
OWNED BY table_name.id;
```